# rexml - How to print empty node with close tag

Tags: ruby, rexml

```
require 'rexml/document'
str = File.readlines('myxml.xml').join # '<a></a>'
el = REXML::Document.new str
p el.to_s # "<a/>"
```

I want `<a></a>` instead of `<a />`.
How can I get this with rexml in ruby?

Comment: Show your attempt, please.

Answer (score 1):

Since it’s an XML, the elements got collapsed unless there is a [possibly emply] node nested:

```
el.root.add_text ''
el.to_s
#⇒ "<a></a>"
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the origin rather than modify it? Assume I am parsing an xml file, it is not applicable to inspect all nodes, right?